# error while reading hbase 1.2.5 table in spark 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

spark version - 2.4.0
hbase version - 1.2.5
scala version.2.11.8

Everything is setup in local VM.

packages imported

spark-shell --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.3,org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.2.5,org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.2.5,org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:1.2.5,org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop2-compat:1.2.5,org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:1.2.5  --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/

In hbase shell:

```
creating table:
 create  'cardata','software','hardware','other'

inserting data to table:

put 'cardata','v001_H','hardware:alloy_wheels','yes'
put 'cardata','v001_H','hardware:anti_Lock_break','yes'
put 'cardata','v001_H','software:electronic_breakforce_distribution','yes'
put 'cardata','v001_H','software:terrain_mode','yes'
put 'cardata','v001_H','software:traction_control','yes'
put 'cardata','v001_H','software:stability_control','yes'
put 'cardata','v001_H','software:cruize_control','yes'
put 'cardata','v001_H','other:make','hyundai'
put 'cardata','v001_H','other:model','i10'
put 'cardata','v001_H','other:variant','sportz'
```

in repl

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase._
import spark.implicits._


def carCatalog = s"""{
"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"cardata"},
"rowkey":"key",
"columns":{
"alloy_wheels":{"cf":"hardware", "col":"alloy_wheels", "type":"string"},
"anti_Lock_break":{"cf":"hardware", "col":"anti_Lock_break", "type":"string"},
"electronic_breakforce_distribution":{"cf":"software", "col":"electronic_breakforce_distribution", "type":"string"},
"terrain_mode":{"cf":"software", "col":"terrain_mode", "type":"string"},
"traction_control":{"cf":"software", "col":"traction_control", "type":"string"}
}
}""".stripMargin

val hbaseDF=spark.read.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->carCatalog)).format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").load()
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog$.apply(HBaseTableCatalog.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.<init>(HBaseRelation.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:51)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
  ... 53 elided
```

Everything is setup in local VM.

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/SHC-on-HDP-3-0-With-spark-2-4/td-p/236356

Comment: changed all jackson jars version from 3.5.6 to 3.2.10. it worked

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` usually means the library version found at runtime is not the expected one (used at compile time).

It might be introduced by your platform adding default libraries (on your behalf with `spark-submit` command) and conflicting with the libraries you're using while developing.

A common solution is called `shading` and can be defined when creating your assembly jar (in build.sbt for instance).

You can refer to this link : https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading

Comment: I am using spark shell. I am not understanding it, do i need to change the source code of the dependency?  I added shades in pom.xml